# In new Linux kernel, what is a replacement for '.(in)active_list' fields from 'struct zone'?

Tags: c, linux

I keep receiving the following error message while compiling the code below.

```
mem_info/sys_mem_stats.c: In function ‘sys_memstats’:
mem_info/sys_mem_stats.c:157: error: ‘struct zone’ has no member named ‘active_list’
mem_info/sys_mem_stats.c:157: error: ‘struct zone’ has no member named ‘active_list’
mem_info/sys_mem_stats.c:162: error: ‘struct zone’ has no member named ‘inactive_list’
mem_info/sys_mem_stats.c:162: error: ‘struct zone’ has no member named ‘inactive_list’
```

---

```
#include<linux/linkage.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/memstats.h>
#include<linux/sched.h>
#include<asm/uaccess.h>
#include<linux/mm.h>
#include<linux/mmzone.h>
#include<linux/vmstat.h>
#include<linux/page-flags.h>
#include<linux/timer.h>
#include<linux/page-flags.h>



asmlinkage int sys_memstats(void){
struct zone * zone;
struct page * page; 

long active_count = 0;
long inactive_count = 0;
long active_ref_bit_count = 0;
long inactive_ref_bit_count = 0;

struct list_head * pos1;
struct list_head * pos2;

for_each_zone(zone)
{
  spin_lock_irq(&zone->lru_lock);
  list_for_each(pos1, &(zone->active_list)){
  active_count++;
  page = list_entry(pos1, struct page, lru);
  active_ref_bit_count += test_bit(PG_referenced, &page->flags);
   }

  list_for_each(pos2, &(zone->inactive_list)){
  inactive_count++;  // see zone->nr_inactive
  page = list_entry(pos2, struct page, lru);
  inactive_ref_bit_count += test_bit(PG_referenced, &page->flags);
}
spin_unlock_irq(&zone->lru_lock);
}

printk("1. active_count:           %lun", active_count);
printk("2. inactive_count:         %lun", inactive_count);
printk("3. active_ref_bit_count:   %lun", active_ref_bit_count);
printk("4. inactive_ref_bit_count: %lun", inactive_ref_bit_count);
printk("5. num_active_to_inactive: %lun", num_active_to_inactive);
printk("6. num_inactive_to_free:   %lun", num_inactive_to_free);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: So then stop using the members that don't exist?

Comment: The fields used to be present in older linux kernels, in recent kernels the struct zone changed noteably.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense, i tried searching for them however, none really matched up. Any idea what they might be?